# Building an event's page inviting users displaying invited users in the show page of the particular event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

1. I want to populate my show page so, users can be invited by name which will display a pending status until users accept
2. Do I set up a new invitation model again because I already have a through association that has an attended event and the users attending the event
3. I would love to be able to set up an in-app notification if I can that user can accept or decline

These are my models

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_attendances, foreign_key: :event_attendee_id
  has_many :attended_events, through: :event_attendances, source: :attended_event
  has_many :hosted_events, foreign_key: :host_id, class_name: 'Event'  
end

 class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_attendances, foreign_key: :attended_event_id
  has_many :event_attendees, through: :event_attendances, source: :event_attendee
  belongs_to :host, foreign_key: :host_id, class_name: 'User'
  scope :past_events, ->(time) { where('date < ?', time) }
  scope :upcoming_events, ->(time) { where('date > ?', time) }
end

class EventAttendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event_attendee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :host, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

My controllers
Event_attendance
class EventAttendancesController < ApplicationController
def new
@event_attendance = EventAttendance.new
end

```
  def create
    @event_attendance = current_user.event_attendances.build(attendants_params)
    if @event_attendance.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def attendants_params
    params.require(:event_attendance).permit(:event_attendee_id, :attended_event_id, :host_id)
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_events = @user.hosted_events.order('date DESC')
    @attending = @user.attended_events
    @upcoming = @user_events.upcoming_events(Time.zone.now)
    @past = @user_events.past_events(Time.zone.now)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome to Eventte'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

Comment: you could also just add a status to `EventAttendance`, which looks like your invite basically.  So showing invites that are pending/accepted/declined there.

Comment: On the `EventAttendance` or the `Invite`?

Comment: I think you could just add it to `EventAttendance`